# Wordpress and Htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, htaccess

Removing RewriteBase / from my htacess has sped up my site which is still working correctly.
Is it really required and what is it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'RewriteBase /' is not needed. RewriteBase allows you to change your internal directory structure to something other than what a browser sees. IE: If all your files are in 'http://mydomain.com/site', but you wanted 'http://mydomain.com' to be the path browsers see, you would use a `RewriteBase /site` and apache's mod_rewrite would happily add that substitution for you.

A `RewriteBase /` is not necessary.

Comment: I guess if it were required - my site would break?

Comment: oops - it does break the site. Without it /wp-admin/ uses the user path in Apache... /usr/www/ etc - it looks like it is necessary for Worpdress to function correctly.